# Where can I find out when I installed an app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, logging

Is there a Play Store log file?

Or should I be looking where apps are installed on the phone for time/date stamps?

Comment: there is another possible that is if your device is rooted then you can access your /system folder.There you can see all installing files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[TitaniumBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) also displays this when you go to the batch (backup/restore) tab. You can have it sort your apps by date of installation, name, size and so on.

It should be noted that you need to root your phone to do so.

Answer (score 16):

There are many third-party apps which shows the install and update time of the installed apps. I've tested three of them and have given instructions to use them for the task at hand.

### [App Manager](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager/)

Install it → tap on three dots line in upper-right area → Sort → Last update.

If you click on an app entry there you can also see its Installer name in the App Info (scroll down to the bottom) section.

### [Applications Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo)

Install and launch the app → tap your app's entry.

### [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2)

Install and launch the app → from the left sidebar select *Applications → User apps* → tap on your app's entry.

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it; order of images: Applications Info, and Solid Explorer)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

---

## Command-line

If you want a command-line way, follow these instructions:

Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and execute the command:

```
adb shell dumpsys package
```

You might end up with overwhelming information about all the installed packages including the  date/time stamp you're seeking. If you want the said stamps for a specific package whose [package name](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/96277) you're aware of, then enter:

```
adb shell 'dumpsys package PKG_NAME | grep -e "firstInstallTime" -e "lastUpdateTime"'     # replace PKG_NAME with the package name of your app
```

Its output possibly would be like,

```
firstInstallTime=2015-07-04 15:49:50
lastUpdateTime=2015-07-04 15:49:50
```

**Note** that the info is originally available in the file */data/system/packages.xml*.

Alternatively, if you've Google Play Store installed, then [take its backup using ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices), [extract the backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/how-do-you-extract-an-apps-data-from-a-full-backup-made-through-adb-backup) to locate the database *localappstate.db*. Open that file in PC using an SQLite database viewer like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) or on Android using apps like [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor) / [aSQLiteManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager). The said apps may need root access so I recommend to stick with the SQLite viewer for PC.

The table *appstate* in that file has the columns *first_download_ms* *delivery_data_timestamp_ms*. The latter shows when the app was installed and the former shows when the download was initiated by Play Store.

**Limitation:** Play Store wouldn't show date/time stamp for side loaded apps.

Comment: can we detect by this dumpsys command if it was installed from Play Store or from apk?

Comment: Yes, search for the string 'installerPackageName' in the dump. Alternatively, type the command "adb shell pm list packages -i PKG_NAME".

Comment: if it is empty (not found), does it mean I need to worry about malicious intrusion?

Comment: @Suncatcher It means that it was not installed by an another package, such as an installer. The app was either sideloaded by the user, or, it was shipped by the oem.

Comment: I see that you have asked this as a question. Did you try that second adb command I mentioned in the comment? Xiaomi could have made changes in some standard strings in the  dump so that's what you may have found nothing in it. Try that other command. If you are using Android 8 or above, sideloaded apps are assigned the installer name of the system's package installer app.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find a place in the stock-system which tells this. But there are useful tools around like [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) which display this information along (besides, AppMonster allows you to backup your apps, and in the [Pro-Version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro) even does so automatically on install as well as update -- so you can revert to a previously installed version easily in case of trouble with an update).

Answer (score 1):

One can use [Smart App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.SmartUninstaller) (gratis) to view the installation date of an application. I tested it on Android 12 with a Pixel 6 and it worked. Screenshot:

[image]