# History of installed/uninstalled apps

Tags: applications, installation, uninstallation, logging, history

I don't know if there is already a thread about this particular issue, but if so forgive me. I would like to know how can I see the date when I installed and uninstalled a certain app some time ago (provided that I deleted it from Google Play history, so I can't go that way). I've been doing some research and logcat appears everywhere, but I don't see how can it solve my problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See [Where can I find out when I installed an app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25263)

Answer (score 7):

Logcat won't be much help here, as it only lasts back a limited time (it uses a ring buffer with a fixed size, so older entries get overwritten with new ones). Instead, better focus on the package manager:

```
adb shell "pm list packages -u -3"
```

gives you a list of all apps *you* have installed (the `-3` restricts it to apps that didn't come pre-installed – essentially meaning "3rd party"), including those you've already uninstalled (`-u`). The returned list looks like this:

```
package:com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox
package:com.mohammadag.xposedpreferenceinjector
```

This still doesn't give you the details you wanted, so lets bring in some help from [Firelord's answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120158/16575):

First, we need to cut of the leading `package:`, so we modify our command to `pm list packages -u -3 | awk -F: '{print $NF}'`:

```
com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox
com.mohammadag.xposedpreferenceinjector
```

Already better. Now Firelord kicks in mentioning the `dumpsys` command for details, which we integrate in what we have so far:

```
for pkg in $(pm list packages -u -3 | awk -F: '{print $NF}'); do
    dumpsys package $pkg
done
```

That should give you full details for each app, including their install date (`firstInstallTime`), last update (`lastUpdateTime`) and, hopefully also the uninstall-time – unfortunately, on the device I've tested this right now, uninstalled apps didn't turn up despite of the `-u` parameter, which might be a device-specific issue (as the `pm` documentation clearly describes it such).

To give you the same thing as a one-liner which also should work on Windows:

```
adb shell "for pkg in \$(pm list packages -u -3 | awk -F: '{print \$NF}'); do dumpsys package \$pkg; done"
```

Comment: +1. I actually had the same approach in my mind but I rather posted a comment since that `-u` in `pm` didn't yield anything good to me.

Comment: @Firelord OK, so it's not just me. Maybe it's a deprecated parameter no longer used since Android x.y. As usually, documentation is a rare thing with those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command on Linux:

`adb shell logcat | grep install` for install app see in logcat

`adb shell logcat | grep uninstall` for uninstall app see in logcat

Otherwise In windows you can use Cygwin. [You can download from here](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: Is there anything equivalent for Windows?

Comment: @jabadejat Grep is available for Windows, but not packaged by default.  It should also be part of Busybox for Android, so that you could do the grep-ing on your device rather than your PC.

Comment: Since the log is stored in a circular buffer, so that old entries get overwritten typically within a day, this doesn't seem like it would help find the date of installing an app.

Comment: How to obtain the size of Logcat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat

Comment: On Windows: `adb shell "logcat | grep install"`. Note the quotes: this tells `adb shell` to run the whole thing on Android – where it finds the `logcat` command as well as `grep`. But the point is: limited use. This way you might see what happened in the last few minutes – but for sure not a couple of days back.

Comment: PS: I've just done a test-uninstall. Your command didn't yield that. What worked: `adb shell "logcat -v time | grep -i uninstall"`. Note the `-i` for case insensitive grep (the log has it as "Uninstall"), plus the `-v time` parameter (OP wanted to see *when* that happened, not only *that* it happened :)