# How to get the installation date and time of application?

Tags: applications

I want to find the installation date and time of the applications in my mobile. Where is it stored? In Ubuntu it can be found from the `/var/log/dpkg.log`. What about Android? I am using Android 4.1.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find out when I installed an app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25263/where-can-i-find-out-when-i-installed-an-app)

Answer (score 12):

There are several apps to use, but I like using [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective).

It's easy, concise, and fully detailed. **This will tell installation time** plus a lot more.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for pic edit, for some reason earlier wrong screenshot got uploaded when posting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888768/package-added-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-work . These are added to comments, because it would make the answer off-topic according to scope of Android Enthusiast. I included these links because they are relevant and useful, but not for end-user.

Comment: Thanks. App detective is the best. It was able to determine the date of installation of all apps even the apps installed prior to the installation of app detectives

Answer (score 3):

When every application is installed you get a Package_Added broadcast. You can save that instance of time and date when you receive the broadcast and store it locally and retrieve it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think some sort of log files will be there ..right ?

Comment: I have never come across any Api to access these information. I have posted the solution as one of a probable solution.

Comment: What method are you using for obtaining `Package_Added` broadcast? What steps are taken?......this way anybody reading this would be able follow along and duplicate the results. Thanks

Comment: You can add a receiver intent: "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" in your manifest file and write a broadcast receiver for this receiver. Catch action "Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED" ij your receiver and fetch the application installed name by : intent.getData() . Save this as string in database and fetch date as well and save . This way you can get the application installed name and date. I have also a link to show how to create the broadcast for this in my github: https://github.com/kodered/Application-Monitor

Answer (score 2):

[Changelog Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cypressworks.changelogviewer) is an app that catches the Package_Added broadcast and logs all installations and updates of packages.  This only works for apps added/updated after it was installed.

You could also look at the creation times of the directories in .../sdcard0/Android/data - though not all apps appear to create a directory there, and I'm not sure if it's done at install time, or first run, etc.