# How can I view history of application updates/installations?

Tags: updates, installation, history

I erroneously updated an application in the Google Play store. The update appears to have deprecated some features and I'd like to revert back (e.g. sideload the APK) of the previous working version. Unfortunately I have no idea what version it was and it would be an exhausting task to determine it through trial and error. Is there any log or history of previously installed application *versions*? I'm on a custom ASOP 4.4.2 ROM with root access, Xposed framework, adb, and all the normal tools of the trade. Is there any way to definitively resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find out when I installed an app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25263/where-can-i-find-out-when-i-installed-an-app)

Comment: Answer by Firelord in above question, I am certain will answer

Comment: From what I can tell, `dumpsys package PKG_NAME` displays the last update time and currently installed version. It doesn't list the previously installed versions. I'll tear into the sqlite DB's referenced in the aforementioned answer as well, but it doesn't look promising.

Comment: Which app is it? // See if /data/system/uiderrors.txt contains entries for your app. If not, then you'll have to go with trial and error. Between the `firstInstallTime` in your device and last update time of the app in Play Store, find the versions available on third-party websites and try them. It would be a pain if the app was frequently updated. 

From this time on, make a log of the current version and the updated version of an app to avoid getting into this situation again.

Comment: It's the Youtube app. The last update removed the ability to fast-forward/rewind so I'm trying to revert it. There was nothing recent in uiderrors.txt. I've tested quite a few versions between my last backup and the most recent update to no avail. Unfort in this case the YT app is one of those that gets frequent updates.